# How to use an API-provided proxy with rotating proxy middleware in Scrapy?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape websites using Scrapy and want to use an API-provided proxy with the rotating proxy middleware. The proxy is provided by an API endpoint that returns a new proxy IP with each request.
I have already installed the scrapy-rotating-proxies package and configured it with the rotating proxy list in the settings.py file. However, I'm unsure how to integrate the API-provided proxy into the rotating proxy middleware.

## settings.py

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = [
    'http://api.scrape.do/?token=MyToken&url=https://httpbin.org/ip?json',
]
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

looks like API you are using is not providing proxies, rather it will return you the HTML of scraped page

You need to provide the page you want to scrape http://api.scrape.do/?token=MyToken&url=http://stackoverflow.com/ and it will return you the page